# JS code to count words on page, not in the html file

Tags: javascript

I saw a question in the past, but it only counted words inside of a certain class. I want my code to print out the amount of words shown in the page from many different types of tags and classes. For example:

From w3schools

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 3+9;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code prints out the value of 3+9 which is going to be 12 at the id location. I want to count the words on the page, in this case it would be 7 ("My First Web Page" from h2 and "My First Paragraph" from p. I'm unsure of how to do this but I assume it would be something similar to the given code.

Comment: Take a look at [HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Comment: This question will also depend on your definition of a "word". Are the numbers in an ordered list words? (<ul>)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) to get the text of the webpage. Then you could use a pattern to split the string into an array by whitespace characters. Then the length of the string should be your word count.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.body.innerText.split(/\s/).length
```

Comment: Nevermind, I see why it is returning this now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Boolean` as shorthand to filter out the falsey `''` values that are present after the `split`.

```js
const allText = document.body.innerText;
const allWords = allText.split(/\s/).filter(Boolean);
const numWords = allWords.length;

document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML = numWords;
```

```html
<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>
<p id="demo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If using javascript need a `innerText` then `split(/\s/).filter(Boolean)`

***Why use a Filter(Boolean)?***
In javascript is very very important to detect a valid word.
Try, if you only use like `innerText.split(/\s/).length` will get a different count.

**This example javascript**

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("counted").innerText.split(/\s/).filter(Boolean).length
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="counted">
<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery Example**, Also

```js
var length = $("#counted").text().trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;
$('#demo').html(length);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="counted">
<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My First Paragraph.</p>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```